# streamline plot with color in bokeh

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I have a pic of streamline plot made by matplotlib. I want to put the same color as matplotlib(Inferno). I tried to look up the same function as `color` in `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot`. Is there any way that I can represent color based on the value of the data?
This is what I did with `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew9Ft.png)

I tried `bokeh.palettes` and there was inferno() function which shows inferno color depending on the numbers from 0~256.[Inferno](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html#bokeh.palettes.inferno)
It seemed working but the the color was represented differently from what matplotlib showed. This is my result with Bokeh. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZHQZ.png)
Bokeh seemed showing colors randomly, not based on the value(which means the higher the value is the brighter the value is).

```py
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import BasicTickFormatter, ColorBar, BasicTicker, LinearColorMapper
import numpy as np
from bokeh.palettes import Inferno256, inferno
import bokeh.plotting as blt
from streamline import streamlines #a package that I made
for comp in range(0,3):
   fig = []
   fig.append(blt.figure())
   x = np.linspace(-6.02138592, 6.02138592, nElem[0]) #Elem[0] = 24
   y = np.linspace(-5.8125, 5.8125, nElem[1]) #Elem[1] = 32

   xs, ys = streamlines(x, y, data[..., 6].transpose(), data[..., 
   7].transpose(), density=1) 
   ''' a fuction to make x velocity and y velocity. here xs and xy are 
   232 However it varies based on the range of x and y. It means it 
   could go over 256.'''

   magnitude = np.sqrt(values[..., 2*comp]**2 
                       + values[..., 2*comp+1]**2) 
   #it will make the lines have color depending on this value

   fig[comp].multi_line(xs, ys, color=inferno(len(xs)), line_width=2, 
   line_alpha=0.8) # I need to change len(xs) because sometimes it 
   exceeds 256

   mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Inferno256',

                              low=np.amin(magnitude.transpose()), 

                              high=np.amax(magnitude.transpose()))


   color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, 
                        width=7, 
                        location=(0,0),           
                        formatter=BasicTickFormatter(precision=1),
                        ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=4), 
                                           label_standoff=10, 
                                           border_line_color=None,
                                           padding=2,
                                           bar_line_color='black')

   fig[comp].add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
   gp = gridplot(children=fig, toolbar_location='right', 
                 ncols=2, merge_tools=True)
   show(gp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a matplotlib stream plot first:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

w = 3
Y, X = np.mgrid[-w:w:100j, -w:w:100j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig, ax = pl.subplots()
strm = ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U, linewidth=2, cmap='viridis')
```

and then get the line and color data:

```
lines = strm.lines
pathes = lines.get_paths()
arr = lines.get_array().data
```

use the data to create a `multiline`, use `linear_map` and `palette` to set the color of the lines:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256

lines = strm.lines
pathes = lines.get_paths()
arr = lines.get_array().data

points = np.stack([p.vertices.T for p in pathes], axis=0)
X = points[:, 0, :].tolist()
Y = points[:, 1, :].tolist()

fig = figure()
mapper = linear_cmap(field_name="color", palette=Viridis256, low=arr.min(), high=arr.max())
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=X, y=Y, color=arr))
fig.multi_line("x", "y", line_color=mapper, source=source, line_width=3)
show(fig)
```

Comment: It looks great! I will try and let you know if it's working.

Comment: What do `points = np.stack([p.vertices.T for p in pathes], axis=0)`, `X = points[:, 0, :].tolist()`, `Y = points[:, 1, :].tolist()` and `color` in `ColumnDataSource(dict(x=X, y=Y, color=arr))` function??

Comment: It works really great!! but can I ask you if you know the way to put `arrow` in each line in the streamline? Just like the streamline plot in `matplotlib`